# c# generate random number with trend and max and min offset

Tags: c#, random

I have a function that generates a double number between 0 and 2.2:

```
Random random = new Random();
double value= random.NextDouble() * (2.2 - 0) + 0;
```

This works great but what I need is to generate the next number with a delta not exceeding 0.2 (positive or negative), i.e. the next random value is within `0.2` of the previously generated one.

For example: If the first random number is: `1.3434434`, the next random number should be in the range between `1.5434434` and `1.1434434`. The numbers can have a trend going up and then could go down but the difference between the previously generated and the new one cant be greater than `0.2`.

Any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Just generate a random number between -0.2 and 0.2 and sum with the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a couple of extension methods to aid with this task. `GenerateTrend` will generate an infinite enumerable of numbers, and the difference between two consecutive numbers is never going to be larger than `delta`.

```cs
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> GenerateTrend(this Random random, double start, double delta)
    {
        var last = start;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return last;
            last = random.NextDouble(last - delta, last + delta);
        }
    }

    public static double NextDouble(this Random random, double from, double to)
        => random.NextDouble() * (to - from) + from;
}
```

Use like this:

```cs
var random = new Random();
var start = random.NextDouble(0, 2.2);
var numbers = random.GenerateTrend(start, 0.2).Take(20).ToArray();
```

As you can see, this being an infinite generator, the calling code is responsible for limiting the amount of random numbers it's taking. In this example, I limit the generation to 20 items by using `Take(20)`.